# Marking rows, based on value of other rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble of multiple values, most importantly containing date and name. For each row of that tibble, I want to check the other rows of that tibble to see if any of the the other dates is equal to the data plus 60 seconds. If so, the row can be marked not unique and removed, if not, the row is marked as unique.

This should be done until all remaining rows are marked unique.

Via dplyr and piping I have made the tibble, but can't seem to filter it properly.

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  date                name      unique
  <dttm>              <chr>     <lgl> 
1 2019-05-10 17:57:00 Item Name FALSE 
2 2019-05-10 17:57:00 Item Name FALSE 
3 2019-05-10 18:11:00 Item Name FALSE 
4 2019-05-10 18:12:00 Item Name FALSE 
5 2019-05-10 18:13:00 Item Name FALSE 
6 2019-05-10 18:13:00 Item Name FALSE 
7 2019-05-10 18:14:00 Item Name FALSE 
8 2019-05-10 18:14:00 Item Name FALSE 
9 2019-05-10 18:15:00 Item Name FALSE
```

So, this tibble is shown pre-filter, all unique values are still set to false. Now in essence, I'd want to run;

```
lookup <- rawlist %>%
  filter(date == date + 60)
```

On every row, row by row and if the result comes back with a rowcount higher then 0, mark the row as not unique and remove it. If it comes back as 0, mark it as unique.

Obiviously, that doesn't work as it just compares the date to itself every row. I feel like I am missing some sort of recursion method here.

One more catch is, if a row is already marked unique, it shouldn't be considered a match for the function.

So, row 1 and 2 should be marked unique.
And row 3 shouldn't be, since row 4 is exactly 60 seconds more.

The intermediate tibble should look like this, but I can't get to that point;

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  date                name      unique
  <dttm>              <chr>     <lgl> 
1 2019-05-10 17:57:00 Item Name TRUE 
2 2019-05-10 17:57:00 Item Name TRUE 
3 2019-05-10 18:11:00 Item Name FALSE 
4 2019-05-10 18:12:00 Item Name FALSE 
5 2019-05-10 18:13:00 Item Name FALSE 
6 2019-05-10 18:13:00 Item Name FALSE 
7 2019-05-10 18:14:00 Item Name FALSE 
8 2019-05-10 18:14:00 Item Name TRUE
9 2019-05-10 18:15:00 Item Name TRUE
```

The desired tibble looks like this;

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  date                name      unique
  <dttm>              <chr>     <lgl> 
1 2019-05-10 17:57:00 Item Name TRUE 
2 2019-05-10 17:57:00 Item Name TRUE
8 2019-05-10 18:14:00 Item Name TRUE 
9 2019-05-10 18:15:00 Item Name TRUE
```

Comment: After the intermediate tibble, could you just do `%>% filter(unique)`

Comment: I've clarified the question, I can't get to the intermediate tibble at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could `arrange` the `date`, subtract the `date` with the lagged `date` and `filter` only the rows which have duration less than 60 seconds.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  filter(difftime(date, lag(date, default = first(date)), unit = "secs") < 60)
```

If you want to add the column `unique`

```
df %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(unique = difftime(date, lag(date, default = first(date)), 
                   units = "secs") < 60) %>%
  filter(unique)
```

---

Or in base R

```
df1 <- df[order(df$date), ]
df[c(TRUE, difftime(df1$date[-1], df$date[-nrow(df)], units = "secs") < 60), ]
```